# How to use array.map() in this setting?

Tags: javascript

Im relatively new to js and trying to figure out how to use map() in this function. Im pretty stuck.. Any ideas?

Im confused because in this case map() is used to iterate over inititalList, and i really dont need the return value, I think..?

```
const addListItems = () => {     
  for (var i = 0; i < initialList.length; i++) {      
    if (i === 0) {          
      listWrapper.innerHTML += `<li class=active data-key=${initialList[i]}>${initialList[i]}</li>`;
    } else {
      // convert to template literals/strings
      listWrapper.innerHTML += `<li data-key=${initialList[i]}> ${initialList[i]} </li>`;
    }
};
```

Ive tried this, but somethings not right:

```
const addListItems = () => {
      let map = initialList.map(item{i === 0 ? listWrapper.innerHTML += <li class=active data-key=${initialList[i]}>${initialList[i]}</li>; :
 listWrapper.innerHTML += <li data-key=${initialList[i]}> ${initialList[i]} </li>; })

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `map()` in your case because `map()` receives a callback that returns something each and every loop, so the `map()` methods returns a new array with the same length as the iterated array. That's what `map()` is meant to do.

In your case you want to return a single `HTML string`, I would suggest you to just use `forEach`:

```
initialList.forEach((item, index) => {
  const element = index === 0 ? `<li class=active data-key=${item}>${item}</li>` : `<li data-key=${item}>${item}</li>`
  listWrapper.innerHTML += element
})
```

Or if you are interested in ES6, you could try `reduce()` instead:

```
listWrapper.innerHTML = initialList.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
  return index === 0 ? acc + `<li class=active data-key=${cur}>${cur}</li>` : acc + `<li data-key=${cur}>${cur}</li>`
}, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also it is a good idea to encapsulate your functions to get a more readable code. Here, instead of writing a long html snippet, I simply speak english inside my loop.

```js
const formatFirstListItem = (item) => item.innerHTML += `<li class=active data-key=${item}>${item}</li>`;

const formatListItem = (item) => item.innerHTML += `<li data-key=${item}> ${item} </li>`;

function addListItems (list){
    return list.map((item, index)=> {
      if(index === 0) return formatFirstListItem(item)
      return formatListItem(item)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` is used for iterating over an iterable collection and creating a new value based on the original one and then **returning it**. In your case, you don't have any purpose of using `map`, you should be using a simple for loop or if you're really into using a function just use `.forEach`:

```
initialList.forEach((item, index) => index === 0 ? listWrapper.innerHTML += `<li class=active data-key=${item}>${item}</li>` : listWrapper.innerHTML += `<li data-key=${item}> ${item} </li>`);
```

Your solution isn't working, because you're not providing a function to the `.map`, but a ternary conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks for youre comment. Its a school assignment and were told to use array.map() although I really dont understand why.